# Scala: how to access variables in a method defined in some other block of code

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I have following code:

```
.hof((key, value) => {
    Some(..some processing result on key,value)
      .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
      .map(x: X => {....my code processing x using key,value with output y})
  }
)
```

I want to abstract out the function I passed to map into a method defined in class.

```
def myMethod(x: X) = {
   y = ....some computation....
   return y
}
```

But I need to have access to key,value in myMethod.

Is there a way to have that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `myMethod` in curried form:

```
def myMethod(key: Key, value: Value)(x: X) = {
  ... uses key and value ...
}
```

Then you can partially apply it in the `map`, passing it the key/value pair that you have at that point:

```
.map(myMethod(key, value))
```

Note that adding key/value pair to `myMethod` signature isn't some kind of "cheating"; if the method needs to use key and value, then it should have them passed as parameters.

This is the great thing about FP; once every function declares all the parameters it operates on, you can compose them easily.

Of course, you could simply place `myMethod` somewhere within the scope where `key` and `value` are going to be accessible (=closure), but by declaring them as parameters you are more flexible and you can place the method anywhere you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the method locally like this:

```
.hof((key, value) => {
  def myMethod(x: X) = {
   ???
  }

  Some(..some processing result on key,value)
    .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
    .map(myMethod)
  }
)
```

Otherwise you are going to have to pass `(key, value)` to the function as arguments.

(See answer from @slouc for tips on how to use currying to make this cleaner)